# How can I use a named pipe as temporary storage in a loop?

Tags: bash, iteration, pipe, named-pipes, fifo

I have a loop, where I'm making incremental modifications to a large file. Rather than write to disk each time, I though I'd use named pipes. However, this means that I'll need a unique name for each iteration of the loop, since I can't seem to redirect output back into the same named pipe.

```
$ mkfifo fifotemp
$ echo qwerty > fifotemp &
$ grep qwe <fifotemp >fifotemp &
$ cat <fifotemp
[hangs]
```

I could create a new named pipe for each iteration, but this seemed inelegant. Is there a better way?

Comment: Disk writes are typically buffered, which means the operating system already accumulates small writes in memory before writing them all to disk in one pass. In other words, you're trying to optimize something that's already been optimized.

Comment: @chepner Do you mean the disk buffer? My files are quite large, easily > 100 MB text files, so I'm presuming that alternating between two on-disk files will exceed the disk buffer.

Comment: The buffer used for named pipes is almost certainly far smaller than that.

Comment: @chepner Perhaps I misunderstand, but the buffer for named pipes won't overflow, they'll just pass to the next pipe concurrently. OTOH, the disk writes (not being pipes) will each have to complete in full before the next step. This would mean the disk buffer would overflow on each step, forcing the write to disk each time, slowing down the script.

Answer (score 1):

Potentially you could use plain pipes and recursive functions. You would need to pass everything into the recursive function to determine when to quit and what processing is needed at each recursion level. This example just adds the recursion level at the front of each line for each level, and quits at level 4:

```
#!/bin/bash

doEdits() {
   while read -r line
   do
      echo "$1 $line"
   done
}

doRecursion() {
   level=$(($1 + 1))
   #echo "doRecursion $level" 1>&2
   if [ $level -lt 4 ]
   then
      doEdits $level | doRecursion $level
   else
      # Just output all the input
      cat
   fi
}

doRecursion 0 < myInputFile > myOutputFile
```

I assume the number of recursion levels is fairly limited, otherwise you could run into system limitations on the number of open processes and pipes.

One advantage here is that each pipe should only need a small buffer. This could also be fast if your machine has multiple processors.

Comment: Wow, that is a fantastic idea. I find it quite complicated for my head to parse though. It's like watching Inception.